# How to upgrade Python in Unix

Tags: unix

I want to upgrade Python in my UNIX server. Current version is :

```
bash-4.4$ python --version
Python 2.6.2
```

I have the Python 3.9.1 .tar.xz file downloaded from Python website.

Could any one let me know step by step how can I upgrade to this new version in UNIX.

Comment: You should issue the command `tar xf Python-3.9.1.tgz` and follow instructions in the file Python-3.9.1/README.rst`.

Comment: Hi Yuri, I have this error  :  `servername% ./configure
checking build system type... powerpc-ibm-aix7.2.4.0
checking host system type... powerpc-ibm-aix7.2.4.0
checking for python3.9... no
checking for python3... no
checking for python... python
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... "aix"
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in ``/h/home74/ciep2c/upgrade/Python-3.9.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See ``config.log' for more details`

Comment: Check config.log There may a clue why installer concludes tha c compier is not working. May be an outdated version.

Comment: If you are running AIX you can use Python3 binaries from AIXTOOLS.
See https://www.python.org/download/other/